# What are firebase.analytics() default logged events for a web app?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-analytics, react-hooks, firebase-analytics

From this page, we get that Firebase is supposed to auto log some events.

https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485?hl=en

I have a web app, this is not a mobile app. This is already confusing, since 99% of the automatically collected events are for mobile apps.

[image]

I would like to just log every `page_view` event. And my web app is a Single Page App, so do I need to log this event on every URL change on my client code?

Right now, the only thing I'm doing is:

```
useEffect(() => {
  props.firebase.analytics();
},[props.firebase]);
```

This code runs only once per user visit on my web app. After `App.js` first mount.

And the weird thing is that I'm getting `page_view` events on my Google Analytics Console:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

the way I do it, is I pass a name on each component/page. Then create a funnel in Google analytics.

> I want to know: **"How many users are getting from my article pages and
>   going to the dashboard"**

I have three components in a flow.

Landing Component

```
useEffect(() => {
  analytics.logEvent('landing_page_view');
});
```

Login Component

```
useEffect(() => {
  analytics.logEvent('login_page_view');
});
```

Dashboard Component

```
useEffect(() => {
  analytics.logEvent('dashboard_page_view');
});
```

Then create a funnel that looks like this. (My data is a bit messed up, but you get the point)

[image]

Hope this helps :)